# How to get the widget data using rest api or some other ways in ESB6.5?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want use another dashboard project based on Javascript to show data ,but I don`t know how to get the Statistical data. Is there any api or some way to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can share what kind of data do you want to portrait in your dashboard. Anyhow you can use the admin services available in ESB 6.5 to get the available data.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Working+with+Admin+Services

Comment: Sorry , I didn't make myself clear.Actrully I want the Analytics Data displayed in EI Analytics Dashboard, such as Request Count,Top APIs by Request Count ,and other widget data displayed in Dashboard.